# hand cursor on input type="file"

Tags: jquery, html, css

i know this question asked many times, and i do research here before ask,

i got the html like this,

```
 <div id="camerathumbnail">
    <input type="file" id="thumbUpload" onchange="fileSelectHandler('module','false')" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp,image/pjpeg,image/png">
 </div>
```

and css class like this :

```
#camerathumbnail {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: 87px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    background: url(/Images/Camera_import_24.png) no-repeat center;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer
}

    #thumbUpload {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

using this css, i am not able to see hand icon, I really want the hand icon on this div, due to input `type=file`, I am not able to get hand icon,

Please provide me easiest fix, I am not using old browsers for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the *entire* `div` as a hand, you can use the `::after` pseudo-element to cover the whole `div` and set that to `cursor:pointer` instead (have changed background to yellow to highlight the div area):

```css
 #camerathumbnail input {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: 87px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    background: url(/Images/Camera_import_24.png) no-repeat center;
    background-color: #ff0;
}

input::after {
    content:'';
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="camerathumbnail">
    <input type="file" id="thumbUpload" onchange="fileSelectHandler('module','false')" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/bmp,image/pjpeg,image/png"/>
</div>
```

Saying that, I generally wouldn't want to mess around with the default behaviour of input controls because making them do things people don't expect isn't good for usability.

Comment: It's a nice thought however you *do* lose UI hover/active states on the button. +1 in any case.

Comment: @George I agree but think it's the only way to style the button that way. So it answers the question, but doesn't mean it's recommended!

Answer (score 5):

You can always use [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
input[type='file'] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" />
```

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with my question ? i also wrote the same css u wrote

Comment: so what is wrong with my question !, if it is that much easier, i never come to stackoverflow :(

Comment: @delmric - you only just added that css for the input in, you can't complain about people suggesting stuff you havent mentioned

Comment: Also you noticed that you have `visibility: hidden` in your parent div?

Comment: visibility: hidden ? so this makes a problem?

Comment: You for Real ? And how come your +rep is from your own questions ?